# If you find a rest spot and there are minions on the board what happens?

Tags: mice-and-mystics

Rest Spot (Fortune, from the search deck) reads:

> Play immediately. If there are no minions on the board, you may remove all wound markers from each mouse and place 1 cheese on the minion wheel.

If there are minions on the board, what happens?  Nothing?

Quick forum scan seems to indicate that you might be able to discard the card for cheese but also say that you might be able to keep the card in your hand for later, which is not how I read the card.  Any idea on more formal ruling/rules guidance?

Answer (score 4):

The rules state: If that card is an item, weapon, armor, accessory, scroll or trick, the player may either:

- put it into the searching mouse's pack for later use, or
- immediately discard it for 1 cheese.

Since Rest Spot is not any of the types listed, I don't think you can discard it for cheese.  And "Play immediately" is pretty clear about not holding on to it for later.  So I think you just discard it and nothing happens.

Comment: Seconded. A fortune can be bad and inopportune.